# Titanium : Ti.UI.SIZE doesn't work properly on Android

Tags: android, ios, web, titanium

I generate a tableView in a loop, and i put a label in each row, which has different length of text each time. I set the rows' height like this:

```
height : Ti.UI.SIZE,
```

and it works pretty good, the rows' heights are always big enough to display the full text. But when i swipe up and down, the rows' heights changes for no reason: they become very big or very small, and i have no idea why. I'll paste in the code snippet that causes the problem. It only works bad on Android, it works perfectly on mobileweb.

```
    var i = 0;
    var tableList = Ti.UI.createTableView({
            separatorColor : '#fef3ff',
            top:'88',
    });
    var tableCategoryData = [];
        while(i<answer.QuestionList.length)
            {
                var label = Ti.UI.createLabel({ 
                     text:answer.QuestionList[i].CategoryTitle,
                        color : '#000000',
                        font:{ 
                        color:'#000000', 
                        fontSize:'20sp', 
                        },
                        textAlign:Ti.UI.TEXT_ALIGNMENT_LEFT,
                        left : 13, 
                        top:'10dp',
                    });
                    var rowouter = Ti.UI.createView({
                        bottom:'10dp',
                        touchEnabled: true,
                        height:Ti.UI.SIZE,
                        backgroundColor:'#fef3ff',
                            });//Andris
                    var row = Ti.UI.createTableViewRow({
                        className: 'row',
                        objName: 'row',
                        touchEnabled: true,
                        height:rowouter.height,
                        color: "#000000",
                        font : {
                            color : '#000000'
                        },
                       backgroundColor:'#fef3ff',
                      });

                    rowouter.add(label);
                    row.add(rowouter);
                    tableCategoryData.push(row);
    ++i;
    }
tableList.setData(tableCategoryData);
```

Comment: Okay, so i guess my problem is impossible to solve.

Comment: Have you tried deleting the line in row object, which sets the height as rowouter.height?

Comment: Yes. When there is one label in each row, it works perfectly on Android. When there is anything more than one label in each row, it doesn't work anymore - the rows randomly changes their height when scrolling.

Comment: Have you tried using height: Ti.UI.SIZE in all elements inside row view?

Comment: Yes.I tried many different options, but the result is always the same. If there is anything more than 1 label in the row, the scroll up and scroll down changes the row's height randomly. Has anybody experienced the same problem? I can't believe i'm the only one.